# Find values from table whose column value determines which column from another table to be used for lookup

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 tables with no relationship defined at DDL.

```sql
CREATE TABLE SOURCES(
  ID VARCHAR2(25),
  SOURCE VARCHAR(2),
  VALUE_ID(VARCHAR2(25),
  LAST_UPDATED TIMESTAMP);

CREATE TABLE USERS(
  ID VARCHAR2(25),
  USER_ID VARCHAR(25),
 CLIENT_ID VARCHAR(25));
```

I need to find all those rows from table sources given an input value for column `VALUE_ID`. `VALUE_ID` is set to `USERS.USER_ID` or `USERS.CLIENT_ID` based on the SOURCE column of that row.

```
IF SOURCE = 'A' THEN VALUED_ID = USERS.USER_ID ELSE USERS.CLIENT_ID
```

Any help resolving this would be much appreciated.

Comment: On what column the tables could be joined ..?

Comment: Use a `UNION`. In the first `SELECT` join on users.user_id `WHERE Source = 'A'` and in the second join on users.client_id `WHERE source <> 'A'`

Comment: Apologies, missed a point in my question so please refer to it.

Comment: Just in passing, you should use `varchar2` and not `varchar` in Oracle

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a CASE statement in your join:

```
Select *
FROM SOURCES S
INNER JOIN USERS U 
   on S.Value_ID = CASE WHEN S.SOURCE='A' then U.USER_ID ELSE U.CLIENT_ID END
```

Comment: Apologies, missed a point in my question so please refer to it.

Comment: Wasnt aware I can use case on join. This solved my issue. Many thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Just use `AND` and `OR` in the join condition:

```sql
SELECT *
FROM   sources s
       INNER JOIN users u
       ON (  (s.source =  'A' AND s.value_id = u.user_id )
          OR (s.source <> 'A' AND s.value_id = u.client_id))
```